# How Can we pass function parameter as another function which itself has different parameters?

Tags: php, function, parameters

I have function below :

```
function cache_activity_data($cid,$somefunction) {

  $cache_time = '+15 minutes';
  $cache_id = $cid;
  $expire = strtotime($cache_time);
  $cache = cache_get($cache_id);
  if (!empty($cache->data)) {
    if (time() > $cache->expire) {
      cache_clear_all($cache_id, 'cache_custom_activity_dashboard');
      $report = $somefunction;  // will get from function 
      cache_set($cache_id, $report, 'cache_custom_activity_dashboard', $expire);
    }
    else {
      $report = $cache->data;
    }
  }
  else {
    $report = $somefunction;  // will get from function 
    cache_set($cache_id, $report, 'cache_custom_activity_dashboard', $expire);
  }

  return $report;

}
```

Now `$somefunction` can be like below examples :

```
total_comments_per_user($user->uid);
total_comments_per_user_time_limit($user->uid, $user_year_start);
total_revisions_time_limit($month_ago);
total_revisions_time_limit($year_start);
```

every time I need to pass like 20 different functions. Is that possible I am getting error as at place of varibales I am passing function But I am not able to figure is that possible.

How I want to use :

```
   //want to write this as function 
 $cache_revisions_total = cache_get("total_revisions", "cache_custom_activity_dashboard");
  if (!empty($cache_revisions_total->data)) {
    if (time() > $cache_revisions_total->expire) {
      cache_clear_all("total_revisions", 'cache_custom_activity_dashboard');
      $t_revisions = total_revisions();
      cache_set("total_revisions", $t_revisions, 'cache_custom_activity_dashboard', $expire);
    }
    else {
      $t_revisions = $cache_revisions_total->data;
    }
  }
  else {
    $t_revisions = total_revisions();
    cache_set("total_revisions", $t_revisions, 'cache_custom_activity_dashboard', $expire);
  }
 // want to write this as function end here

  $vars['total_bubbla_rev'] = number_format(($t_revisions / $days_from_rev_start), 2, '.', '');

 // here i want to do same so i need to write function or should i repeat code 
  $y_revisions = total_revisions_time_limit($year_start);
  $vars['yearly_bubbla_rev'] = number_format(($y_revisions / $year_days), 2, '.', '');

// here i want to do same so i need to write function or should i repeat code 
  $m_revisions = total_revisions_time_limit($month_ago);
  $vars['monthly_bubbla_rev'] = number_format(($m_revisions / 30), 2, '.', '');
```

Please suggest, Thanks!

Comment: You cannot pass functions in your parameters. However you can use callbacks. But in your case I don't understand why you are passing `$somefunction` in parameter it seems useless. Can you add in your question the call origine of `cache_activity_data()` ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have edited question as now we can see I need data with my function within function.

Comment: `$report = $somefunction;`  where I need to pass my function according to requirements, Is that will be possible using callbacks, please suggest !

Comment: `cache_activity_data()`  is function I am trying to write to set cache to diffrent kind of data which will be fetched using different function which I was thinking that we can pass using parameters .

Comment: What you need to show in your question is **where** you are calling `cache_activity_data(...)`. But I guess that the answer I posted to your question summarize your problem.

Comment: Please see updated question this is how I want to use, I have to use this almost 30 times so thats why I was trying to create function and do not want to repeat code again and again. Is that possible and thanks for answer

Comment: Well I was probably not clear. What I would like to see is: **a)** where you are calling `total_comments_per_user_time_limit` or `total_revisions_time_limit` or what ever function you have listed. **b)** where you are calling  `cache_activity_data(...)`

Comment: Please see comments in code i used  `$y_revisions = total_revisions_time_limit($year_start); ` and `$m_revisions = total_revisions_time_limit($month_ago); ` and `$t_revisions = $cache_revisions_total->data;` Please let me know if its not clear I will try to make it more clear

Comment: And what about `cache_activity_data(...)` ? Where is this function called in your flow?

Comment: Please see comemnt in code "want to write this as function end here" this is code what I am trying to use in cache_activity_data( ) so that I can use it again and again. where 'total_revisions' is $cache_id example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible options.

**Option 1**

You could use [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). I simplified your function but you'll get the idea:

```
function cache_activity_data($cid, $somefunction) {
    $report = $somefunction();
}
```

Define your functions as anonymous functions:

```
$parm1 = "banana";
$parm2 = "fruit";

$your_function1 = function() use ($parm1, $parm2) {
    echo "$parm1 is a $parm2";
};

$your_function2 = function() use ($parm1) {
    echo $parm1;
};
```

Usage:

```
cache_activity_data($cid, $your_function1);  // shows "banana is a fruit"
cache_activity_data($cid, $your_function2);  // shows "banana"
```

Read carefully through the documentation. Especially the part about variable scopes.

**Option 2**

Another possibility is [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) but this requires you to make a little adjustment to `cache_activity_data()`. You need to add a third parameter which holds an array:

```
function cache_activity_data($cid, $somefunction, $somefunction_parms) {
    $report = call_user_func_array($somefunction, $somefunction_parms);
}
```

Define your functions as usual:

```
function your_function1($parm1, $parm2) {
    echo "$parm1 is a $parm2";
}

function your_function2($parm) {
    echo $parm;
}
```

Usage

```
cache_activity_data($cid, "your_function1", array("banana", "fruit"));  // shows "banana is a fruit"
cache_activity_data($cid, "your_function2", array("banana")); // shows "banana"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this awesome explanations and ways. Just one query where my function is not having any parameter I am passing like  `cache_activity_data($cid, "your_function3", array(""));` Is that will be fine. By usage it works. Thanks again :)

Comment: If you don't have arguments for a certain function pass an empty array: `array()`. `array("")` is not an empty array, it's an array with one element which is an empty string.

Comment: Thanks again for help !

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot pass functions as parameters, however you can use callbacks as explained here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

But in your case, this seems irrelevant as you are not determining the function or changing its value in `cache_activity_data()`.

Therefore, you might want to do like this:

```
$reportDefault = total_comments_per_user($user->uid);
// Or ... $reportDefault  = total_revisions_time_limit, total_comments_per_user_time_limit, etc..
$report = cache_activity_data($cid, $reportDefault);
```

You do not need to add pass `$report` or any function as parameter.

Comment: But at place of $reports  I need different data that will be fetched using different function so I guess its not possible to use single function in this way to cache my data coming from different function ?

Comment: Thanks for your help and efforts +1 may be its not clear to me or i was not able to clear i will try more for now. And this way there will be no user of cache If i will call function before calling cache function.